# React: Passing tailwindcss styling down to component as prop not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I made a little "Blob" which I want to use multiple times with different color/sizes.

```
function Blob() {
    return (<div className="blob w-[800px] h-[800px] rounded-full absolute blur-3xl bg-white"/>);
}
```

In order to make it customizable, I made a prop called "color", which is then used in the className for tailwind:

```
function Blob(props:{color:string}) {
    return (<div className="blob w-[800px] h-[800px] rounded-full absolute blur-3xl {color}"/>);
}
```

Then, I give it a color in the parent code like so:

```
export default function Page() {
  return <>
  <div className="flex">
    <Blob color="bg-white"/>
  </div>
  </>
}
```

However, when I do this second version, the blob diappears, despite it being there when I just define its color like in the first version. Looking for a solution, I found someone saying you need to use the "classnames"-library (`npm install classnames` and then `import classNames from "classnames";`), and then create the classname for tailwind that way:

```
function Blob(props:{color:string}) {
    return (<div className={classNames("blob w-[800px] h-[800px] rounded-full absolute blur-3xl ${color}")}/>);
}
```

However, this also changes nothing. I suspect tailwind might not like the fact I'm combining strings for the `className`, but in my opinion it shouldn't be a problem, especially since it seems to work for other people. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not destructuring your `props` object. It's being typed, but you're not extracting the `color` property. Try the following perhaps?

```
function Blob({ color }: { color: string }) {
    return (
        <div
            className={classNames("blob w-[800px] h-[800px] rounded-full absolute blur-3xl", color)}
        />
    );
}
```

Without the `classnames` package, use backticks to concatenate: `` `h-2 ${myVariable}` ``:

```js
function Blob({ color }: { color: string }) {
    return (
        <div
            className={`blob w-[800px] h-[800px] rounded-full absolute blur-3xl ${color}`}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would I go about doing this for more than one prop (For example, not only "color", but also "width")? It seems  tedious to do what you did for lots of props, isn't there a way to do it with an interface?

Comment: There are two ways you could go about this:

1. You could expose a `className` prop instead of specific `color`, `width` etc. This would greatly simplify the code since you only need to concatenate the `className` to the default class names that you want to add.
2. You could expose and object `style` that includes all your props: (color, width etc) and then you would only use the values:

`function Blob({ style }: { style: { color: string; width: string })` 

In your component you could extract the values and `join` them:

`className={Object.values(style).join(' ')}`.